# Sweet Alert2 not showing up after form validation in CI

Tags: codeigniter, sweetalert2

Hello i'm trying to show up the alert after validation succes ,but the alert not showing up .
code wrong or what ??

```html
public function dashboard()
 {
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
  if($this->form_validation->run() != false){
   echo "<script>
   Swal.fire('Login Success')
   </script>";
  }else{
   $this->load->view('login');
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there any errors logged? I usually close php with then execute the Javascript then open it again.

```
public function dashboard()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
        if($this->form_validation->run() != false){
            ?>
            <script>
                 Swal.fire('Login Success');
            </script>
            <?php
        }else{
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
```